# In Rails, how can I use three collection selects to add 3 has_many values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking to create 3 separate collection_selects to choose players for a team, where Team has_many players. However, if I have the following code 3 times...

```
= f.collection_select :player_ids, @season.players, :id, :name
```

... it only sends one back in the params, since they all point to the same thing.

How can I use three collection selects to add three has_many values?

I do **not** want to use

```
= f.collection_select :player_ids, @season.players, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => true }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting only one in the params, because all three dropdowns share the same html `<select>` element ID and name.

If you don't like the *multiple* approach, the only thing I can think of is specifying manually the dropdown IDs and names as follow:

```
f.collection_select :player_ids, @season.players, :id, :name, {}, {:id => "dropdown_1", :name => "season[player_ids][]"}
f.collection_select :player_ids, @season.players, :id, :name, {}, {:id => "dropdown_2", :name => "season[player_ids][]"}
f.collection_select :player_ids, @season.players, :id, :name, {}, {:id => "dropdown_3", :name => "season[player_ids][]"}
```

The IDs can be whatever you prefer but all three must be different. The real important thing is the **"name" attribute**, as it must match the model you're updating (in this case I suppose it's **season**) and having the final brackets [] will indicate it's an array of IDs (one ID per-dropdown)